# javascript plugin only working when mouse enters the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, gravity

I'm using a javascript plugin called jGravity.js and have managed to make the gravity effect work on the relevant div elements. However the script only starts when the mouse enters the viewport, rather than as soon as the page has loaded.

I've tried the following...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').jGravity({ 
            target: 'div.text',
            ignoreClass: 'name', 
            weight: '10',
            depth: 5,
            drag: true
        });
});
```

I thought this would enable the script to run without prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, but the ```drag``` property may be related, you might try setting it to false if you haven't already.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington I've tried this but still no luck unfortunately

Comment: That seems to be the way the plugin operates: `function onDocumentMouseMove() { if (!isRunning) run(); ... `. Maybe you could extend the plugin. Here's a [quick test](https://jsfiddle.net/akp73zon/) just calling the `run()` function manually.

Comment: @showdev perfect that works!

Answer (score 0):

You could always add to your script the function that makes the mouse enter the viewpoint,
other than that I don't know.